# Zxing scan codes with minimum length

Tags: android, size, barcode, zxing, code128

I am using to scan Zxing `code128` and `ITF` in my Android application. 
The application works perfectly and reads bar codes correctly. But, I have a problem. The paper where the barcode is contains several barcodes. These bar codes are different lengths and are close together. As these are `code128`, often scanner reads the bar code not desire. 
I want to know if it is possible to ignore the scanner bar code `code128` whose length is less than 22 digits. Is it possible? 
Thanks

Comment: Ignore it in your application logic.